# How do you unit test an algorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unit-testing

I've ran into a situation I'm not sure how to test: algorithms. Specifically, I'm attempting to write the Adler32 method and create a unit test for it, but I hit a brick wall at this point.

My first attempt ended up being a shortened version of the same code I had in my method, which just seems very wrong to do. My next attempt was to have a table of input values with expected results, then compare the expected results to actual results... this seemed like a good idea until I realized that the only way I know how to populate this table would be by running the algorithm. So I'm pretty much stuck. How does one go about unit testing an algorithm without reusing the algorithm in the unit tests (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: Not sure what your problem with passing *known* input and verifying output matches *known* result... Like "add two numbers" will be tested with known input `{2,2}` and verified that result is `4` (without running `2+2` in the test)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I have no problem with that, except the only way I know how to generate known input/result is by reusing the same algorithm I'm attempting to test. How do I know the result is **correct** for an untested algorithm?

Comment: Known to be good Inputs/Outputs will be fine, but as you stated you need to calculate the output. One way would be to use an already proven to be working Adler32 implementation. Or you could go about breaking the algorithm down into parts that you can test.

Comment: [RFC 1950](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1950#section-9) contains a reference implementation of Adler-32 that can be used to generate test vectors.

Comment: I'd expect most known algorithms (like the Adler32 you've mentioned) have test data... For new ones you've invented the only option I can think of is to ask multiple people independently implement algorithm preferable in multiple languages and get test data that way (if computing by hand is out of question)...

Comment: Side note: I think this question may be more suitable for  http://programmers.stackexchange.com too... and maybe Computer Science one - http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You normally do not test *algorithms*, but rather their implementations.  Since an algorithm is a mathematical concept, it is usually *proven* rather than tested.  This is an important distinction, especially for known/named algorithms as their implementation can be tested against sets of input and known correct outputs that, at worst, can be derived from prior implementations that are known to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

Use a table of inputs and known outputs as you described. You need to get the outputs from another implementation of the same algorithm from a source you know is accurate.

If you're implementing an algorithm that doesn't have readily available input/output data, then re-implement the algorithm another way, such as in Excel, and generate data you know to be accurate.  We do this often with statistical calculations for reports where we can generate data easily in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If we would talk about unit testing, as you want to provide test for one method/class, you must supply input and verify results of your algorithm.

As your algorithm makes some calculation which you can not trust by default (it's the point of testing), you need to verify results according to **constant values**. E.g. you supply `5` and your method return `17`. Which is either fine or not - your test pass or fail.

Where to get `17`? Use paper and pencil, online calculation website, whatever way which you can trust.

Test, especially unit ones, must be **simple and very light**. You should not provide some alternative approach how to calculate results and verify them against those from production code. This approach brings you two different implementation which you would have to maintain, refactor etc.

Obviously you can provide table of inputs and expected outputs, not just `5` and `17`.